# How to push additional fields into an Array in Php ?

Tags: php, arrays, loops, foreach

Hello I'm looking to find the best practice to push an additional field into an Array with php.
I've tried both array_push and its equivalent $array[] = $var; but its not what I'm looking to get.

I have a loop like so:

```
    foreach($lakesNearby as $lakes){
        $dist = $this->getDistance($lat, $lng, $lakes['latitude'], $lakes['longitude'], $unit);
        $lakes['distance'] = $dist;
        $lakesReturned[] = $lakes;
    }
```

But I'm sure there is a better way to combine the two last lines and push it into $lakesNearby ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Alex said in the comment:

Just for completeness, see php.net/manual/de/control-structures.foreach.php : "In order to be able to directly modify array elements within the loop precede $value with &. In that case the value will be assigned by reference.

```
<?php
$arr = array(1, 2, 3, 4);
foreach ($arr as &$value) {
    $value = $value * 2;
}
// $arr is now array(2, 4, 6, 8)
unset($value); // break the reference with the last element
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

Hmmm..., maybe that:

```
foreach($lakesNearby as &$lakes){
    $lakes['distance'] = $this->getDistance($lat, $lng, $lakes['latitude'], $lakes['longitude'], $unit);
}
```

all data will be in $lakesNearby array, you don't need another array.

Comment: +1 for answering the question. 
Just for completeness, see http://php.net/manual/de/control-structures.foreach.php : 
"In order to be able to directly modify array elements within the loop precede $value with &. In that case the value will be assigned by reference."